# Dynamic timespan format string

Tags: c#, timespan, format-string

I want to set my `TimeSpan` format string dynamically. It means if the time span value is negative format string should be different from positive one. the point that when I want to set format string I don't know the value of `TimeSpan`!

For example: I want to have -03:01:01 for negative timespan and 003:01:01 for positive value

the code is

```
columns.Add(new TimeSpanColumnInfo(col.PropertyName, col.TitlePersian, col.TitleEnglish, "ddd\\:hh\\:mm"));
```

witch third arguments is formatstring

Comment: Nope, no idea what you're trying to do. Example input and output and example code that you've tried needed.

Comment: @AntP more examples are needed yet?

Comment: You still haven't posted the code you've tried. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Okay, now I see you have shared a single line of code, in which you add some unknown object to some unknown collection - how is this supposed to help any one answer the question? You need to share enough information to *make the question answerable*. Put some effort into the question if you want people to put effort into the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your question still isn't clear but if you have a `TimeSpan` object called `t` you can conditionally choose a format string by doing the following:

```
string format = t < TimeSpan.Zero ? @"\-dd\:hh\:mm" : @"ddd\:hh\:mm";
```

If you really need to specify the format in advance of knowing the value of `t` (questionable), then you could change your method signature to accept a `Func<TimeSpan, string>` and pass in the following as an argument:

```
o => o < TimeSpan.Zero ? @"\-dd\:hh\:mm" : @"ddd\:hh\:mm"
```

[More info on `Func<T, TResult>`.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: the problem is that when I want to set string format I don't have value of t!

Comment: +1 for the option for passing a formatting function.  That's a good suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for something like [the section separator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#SectionSeparator).

```
string s = someNumber.ToString("00;(00)");
```

In the above example, positive values are output with two digits and negative values are output with two digits wrapped in parenthesis.

Unfortunately, the section separator is only valid for custom *numeric* formats.  The [custom timespan formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) do not include a section separator.